# Parameters that denote the dynamic range, symmetry and slope of the sigmoid function respectively in software WEKA

Tags: parameters, artificial-intelligence, weka, sigmoid

I need the three parameters that denote the dynamic range, symmetry and slope of the sigmoid function respectively in software WEKA. I've alread search on books, papers and manuals without succesfull.

I want to implement a neural network and i need the parameters.

Comment: Take a look at the source code: https://git.cms.waikato.ac.nz/weka/weka/-/blob/main/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/neural/SigmoidUnit.java